# Test HTML div tags

Tags: html

```
<html>
<div>
</div
<div>
</div
<div>
</div
<div>
</div
</html>
```

The content has been removed due to permission and user authentication.

Comment: `IsManager` is the method of `Login` class, isn't it?

Comment: Yes indeed. I would like to mock this method but the Login takes argument of Unit of work and Unit of work class takes argument of context

Comment: Can you show your IsManager method?

Answer (score 1):

You are testing the Login class. The dependencies of that class will need to be mocked.
You'll be mocking IUnitOfWork so there's no need to worry about UnitOfWork itself.

```
var uow = Substitute.For<IUnitOfWork>();
var sut = new Login(uow);
```

Now you can call `sut.IsManager` and assert the results.
Make sure to setup the mock `uow` to behave as you expect in each test case. e.g: Return a non manager user, return a manager.

Comment: But shouldn't I also mock the context as Unit of work depends on the context as an argument?

Comment: I have tried writing up the unit test as you suggested but the mocking for the uow is acting as an integration. When I debug the unit test, when calling my method isManager. Its returning null as uow is being set as null. Looking at the uow from the unit test. the property for Employee is evaluated with an error of "Employee= The function evaluation requires all threads to run." Also the uow target is set to null.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by uow (the mock) acting like an integration. Also I don't understand how "IsManager is returning null as uow is being set to null" It would make it easier to help if you provide the code for IUnitOfWork and Login classes (simplified, the IsManager method on Login class only and from the UoW only the methods used by IsManager)